# count specific items in a nested list (x and y dependencies) inside python

Tags: python, list, nested, dependencies, naivebayes

Example I have these list

```
bersarang=[['Cerah','Tinggi','Lemah','Iya'],['Cerah','Tinggi','Kuat','Iya'],['Mendung','Tinggi','Lemah','Tidak'],['Hujan','Tinggi','Lemah','Iya'],['Hujan','Normal','Lemah','Iya'],['Hujan','Normal','Kuat','Tidak'],['Mendung','Normal','Kuat','Iya']]
```

then I want to count 'Cerah' and 'Iya' to an integer variable, the answer of these count should be 2. is it possible to get the count?
I tried with count but its only count 1 item.

Failed Solution of mine:

```
bersarang.count('Cerah' and 'Iya')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop:

Code Explantation:

1. `count = 0` setting `count` to 0
2. `for sub_l in l:` iterating through the `l`
3. `if set(elems).issubset(sub_l): count += 1` add 1 to `count` if `elems` are in the sublist (`sub_l`)
4. `return count` returning the `count` variable

Code:

```py
def count_elems(elems, l):
    count = 0

    for sub_l in l:     
        if set(elems).issubset(sub_l):
            count += 1

    return count

print(count_elems(['Iya', 'Cerah'], [['Cerah', 'Tinggi', 'Lemah', 'Iya'], ['Cerah', 'Tinggi', 'Kuat', 'Iya'], ['Mendung', 'Tinggi', 'Lemah', 'Tidak'], ['Hujan', 'Tinggi', 'Lemah', 'Iya'],
             ['Hujan', 'Normal', 'Lemah', 'Iya'], ['Hujan', 'Normal', 'Kuat', 'Tidak'],
             ['Mendung', 'Normal', 'Kuat', 'Iya']]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the sub-lists where both values appear, you could do:

```
bersarang = [['Cerah', 'Tinggi', 'Lemah', 'Iya'], ['Cerah', 'Tinggi', 'Kuat', 'Iya'],
             ['Mendung', 'Tinggi', 'Lemah', 'Tidak'], ['Hujan', 'Tinggi', 'Lemah', 'Iya'],
             ['Hujan', 'Normal', 'Lemah', 'Iya'], ['Hujan', 'Normal', 'Kuat', 'Tidak'],
             ['Mendung', 'Normal', 'Kuat', 'Iya']]


def count_values(values, lst):
    s = set(values)
    return sum(s.issubset(l) for l in lst)


res = count_values(('Cerah', 'Iya'), bersarang)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
2
```

Basically the function will check if the values are a subset of each sublist of the list, for this we use [issubset](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/issubset.html), then count using [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

An alternative, albeit slower for large numbers of values, is to do:

```
def count_values(values, lst):
    return sum(all(v in l for v in values) for l in lst)
```

Basically check that [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) values are contained within each sublist.

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with collections counter

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> z = ['blue', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red']
>>> Counter(z)
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'yellow': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pythons built in fuction count

```
bersarang=[['Cerah','Tinggi','Lemah','Iya'],['Cerah','Tinggi','Kuat','Iya'],['Mendung','Tinggi','Lemah','Tidak'],['Hujan','Tinggi','Lemah','Iya'],['Hujan','Normal','Lemah','Iya'],['Hujan','Normal','Kuat','Tidak'],['Mendung','Normal','Kuat','Iya']]

def countit(thing):
    count = 0
    for i in bersarang:
        count += i.count(thing)
    return count
print(countit("Cerah"),countit("Iya"))
```